# Chart.js category y-axis line chart

Tags: chart.js

Using Chart.js 2.0, how to draw a line chart with category y-axis?

Here is my code

```
    var ctx = $("#myChart");
    var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "January",
                data: [{
                    x: -10,
                    y: "January"
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: "February"
                }, {
                    x: 10,
                    y: "February"
                }]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    type: 'category',
                    position: 'left'
                }]
            },
            showLines: false
        }
    });
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lvx4gLn/1/)

In this way, the following graph is generated where not points is shown in the coordinate:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you want a line chart why is there "type: 'bar'" in the 3rd line?

Comment: @DAXaholic It's a typo, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the latest version of chart.js (2.8.0) and your code works.  Can you upgrade the version of Chart.js that you are using?